# how to validate input in list views?

Tags: asp.net

this is my list view

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Year" 
        DataSourceID="AccountValueFundsDataSource" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
........
</asp:ListView>
```

This is my data source

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AccountValueFundsDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Life_InsuranceConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [AccountValueFunds] WHERE [Year] = @original_Year AND [avfcharge] = @original_avfcharge" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [AccountValueFunds] ([Year], [avfcharge]) VALUES (@Year, @avfcharge)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [AccountValueFunds]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [AccountValueFunds] SET [avfcharge] = @avfcharge WHERE [Year] = @original_Year AND [avfcharge] = @original_avfcharge">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Year" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_avfcharge" Type="Decimal" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Year" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="avfcharge" Type="Decimal" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="avfcharge" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Year" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_avfcharge" Type="Decimal" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my question is how to validate input? example if a users enters a string where the type of parameter is decimal or integer??

Comment: Don't you just have to put the desired controls in the InsertItemplate or EditItemTemplate? What am I missing?

Comment: yes i do; but if i want to check the input ie; if a user enters a string while the type is integer how could this be handeled???

Comment: Oh you are asking which validators to use, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle that validation with [RegularExpressionValidator - MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx), [RegularExpressionValidator - W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_regularexpvalidator.asp).

You need the `ValidationExpression` to allow `decimal`s and `integer`s but not allow `string`s.

Check these

[Accept only (0-9) integer and one decimal point(decimal point is also optional).](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=368)

[Input for Numeric values. Handles negatives, and comma formatted values. Also handles a single decimal point](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=329)

[Regular Expression Validator - Numbers only no letters no spaces](http://forums.asp.net/t/897862.aspx/1)